# Unable to make Badge Progress black PopUp disapear/fade_out on Safari iPad

Tags: bug, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

On the reviews section, I tap on the Badges Progress bar and a black PopUp fades in to shows user's reviewing Badges. When I tap back to the same PopUp, the same stays frozen there. I also tried to tap anywhere on the screen but the PopUp still stays there.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "tap back to the same popup"? You tapped in the same place? Because that popup actually opens on *hover*, not on click (or tap for a tablet). So as long as your hypothetical cursor is over it, it will be visible. You should be able to tap anywhere else on the screen to close it.

Comment: @animuson I tap anywhere on the screen or even into the black popup and it never disappears